# Pattern/algorithm for sync arrays of similar objects, suggestions?

Tags: php, algorithm, design-patterns, synchronization

I wrote a class in PHP that represents a contact in an address book, every object has some attributes like names, email, phone number, etc... and it's saved in a database table.
Now I'm many of these contacts and I need to keep them in sync with contacts in Google Contacts (I can access Google Contacts via Google People API).

Object from Google People API are different in structure from my class objects but this is not a big problem, my question is:
what's the best pattern/algorithm to keep in sync two lists of objects?
I need to synchronize creations, modifications and deletions between my software and Google Contacts...

Comment: Why not just directly access / update the google contacts data thru People API ? (Please tell us the reason(s) to maintain two sets of databases containing SAME data and then sync them)

Comment: I could create / update / delete a contact in my database and on Google Contacts at the same time using my software but what would happen when someone were to add / edit / delete a contact directly from Google Contacts or, for example, from a phone that has active contact synchronization?

Comment: what would happen ? of course it should be allowed (do you think you can disallow the users to use their phones to update Google Contacts by himself/herself just because you have created a separate db ?) - and you should then sync from google contacts back to your db . So what is the benefit(s) of having `two databases` over a normal case of db management to maintain a `single, centralized database` ?